# Focus on text field each time the editor loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a normal chat application having 2 sections ie contacts list in one column and their chats in the other column. On selecting a contact from the list, the chat corresponding to the user gets opened. Now I am having a editor / input field in  the chat section which I need to focus when chat section gets loaded and even after I send the message.

```js
document.getElementById("comment").focus();
```

```html
 <div class="row reply">
   <div class="col-sm-11 col-xs-11 reply-main">
     <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" id="comment" placeholder="Enter any message" ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1 reply-send">
       <a id="send" onclick="saveRecordText();" ><i class="fa fa-save fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
   </div>
```

I need to focus the textarea with id comment using Jquery so that the text area is always active for taking input and I dont need to click it each time for entering an input.

Comment: This code works. Are you sure your textarea is the only element having this id in your html document ? Also check that the editor is not nested a `iframe`, in which case you might have to target the `iframe` document instead of the root page document.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery focus function to focus your textarea: https://api.jquery.com/focus/

```js
$(function() {
 // Initial focus
 $('#comment').focus();
 
 // Focus even when focusout
 $('#comment').focusout(function(){
     $('#comment').focus();
 });
});
```

Also you can add $('#comment').focus(); in your saveRecordText() and chat load function you created. If you don't need focus when user focus out then please remove:

```js
// Focus even when focusout
$('#comment').focusout(function(){
  $('#comment').focus();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried this code ? It doesn't work. By the way, forcing focus while the user tries to focus out is a nonsense.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. It works in jQuery. There's many other option. It depends on what user wants in the app. If it doesn't make sense to use focuseout in the app context then he can remove it and use  focus() when chat loads and on sent.

Comment: I just figured out that focus is not set on the `textarea` because it lives in a different frame than the "Run" button in the snippet. Right clicking "Refresh frame" (on the result viewport) will cause the focus to be correctly set. Nonetheless, jQuery is not required and the code in the question actually works ^^

Answer (score 0):

Although the code works perfectly through your code using JavaScript, one can do it using jQuery as below:

```
$(function () {
    $('#comment').focus();
});
```